# TS warning when trying to update the single state property in the react Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setstate

Let's assume that we have the simple react Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface IState {
  a: boolean;
  b: string;
  c: number;
}

class Test extends Component<{}, IState> {
  state = {
    a: true,
    b: 'value',
    c: 7,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ a: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { a, b, c } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {a && b + c}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-shirley-zlxib?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

But I get this message:

```
Argument type {a: boolean} is not assignable to parameter type ((prevState: Readonly<IState>, props: Readonly<{}>) => (Pick<IState, keyof IState> | IState | null)) | Pick<IState, keyof IState> | IState | null
```

I found some approaches that can solve this type of warnings:

1. Replace `IState` to `Partial<IState>`
2. Make all `IState` items optional

```
interface IState {
  a: boolean;
  b: string;
  c: number;
}
```

3. Add `as IState` for `this.setState({ a: false } as IState)`
4. Add the key name every time we execute `setState` `this.setState<'a'>({ a: false } as IState)`
5. Update the whole object:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      a: false,
    }));
```

But I guess they aren't a good way to handle this. So, what is the best way to handle that annoying warning?
UPD: I found that I get this warning only in WebStorm. In CodeSandbox and VSCode there are no warnings

Comment: Do you really want to override the whole state?

Comment: I want to update only one property in the state object

Comment: It would help if you can share a sample in a codebase. May be in https://codesandbox.io/. The versions of TypeScript and React go through a lot of changes, and it'll help you get better answers if others are able to debug this better with that context.

Comment: `setState` sets the state, so you override the whole object. the 5. option is what you should go for.

Answer (score -1):

[Select TypeScript Language Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt5VW.png)

The issie is fixed. Just make sure that `TypeScript Language Service` is selected.